# Find object below the Character Controller

Tags: c#, object, scripting, unity-game-engine

I have a character controller which moves along the z-axis with a constant speed. I'd like to know the floor name under the character controller. The Character controller never collides with the floor. It's a parallel movement. I used a Raycast to find the floor in C# using:

```
myray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
if (Physics.Raycast(myray, myhit, 1000)) {
    Debug.DrawLine (ray.origin, hit.point);
    print(myhit.collider.name);
}
```

This gives an error. Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: What error do you get? And where? Shouldn't it be `myray` in line 3?

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/31775/how-get-object-if-i-know-coordinates.html#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what your issue is, but attaching this behaviour to your character-controlled object will get the name of the first object the raycast hits.

I'm using an inverted layer mask to ignore the "Player" layer, which I set the character-controlled object to. This is so the raycast doesn't hit the object before the floor.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GetFloorName : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public string NameOfRaycastHitObject;

    void Update () 
    {
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        int layerMask = ~(1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player"));
        float distance = 100f;

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hitInfo, distance, layerMask))
        {
            NameOfRaycastHitObject = hitInfo.collider.name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain layerMask?

Comment: I wanted the raycast to check collisions on every layer apart from "Player".

LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player") gives me the layer index, and I turned that into a bitmask by shifting it.

Then I inverted it. The [Unity docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/Layers.html) will probably explain it better that I can.

Comment: getting error : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: That's not enough information to help, unfortunately. I've uploaded the Unity project I used to test with [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1364397/StackOverflow/FloorRaycastExample.zip), maybe that'll help you.